# Dynamic height setting

Tags: html, css

Can anybody help me with the illustration mentioned below?

```
<body>
    <header height="100px"></header>
    <main height="rest of the height of viewport"></main>
</body>
```

I want `<header>` of certain predefined height but want that rest of the height of viewport will be grabbed by `<main>`.

**NOTE: No JavaScript code please.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS

```
header {
    height: 100px;
}

main {
    height: calc(100vh - 100px);
}
```

What happen here is, VH is your viewport height. So, we should subtract it into header height.

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y10p9atj/

Hope it helps.

Comment: nice work.. but viewport height cant work with windows safari

Comment: If you want to support older browser. You should use javascript instead of css. As OP said. No JS. It's also easy doing this on js.

Comment: @JeremyJohn I think he's referring to old browsers.

Comment: @LaraBelle how to contact you?

Comment: @PratikDasa why? What's the matter?

Comment: @LaraBelle Knowledge sharing. As I read your profile and impressed.

Comment: @PratikDasa you can contact me on my email. larabelleluna@gmail.com

Comment: @LaraBelle Thanks. Sent you an email.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Its Automatically Adjusts Any Resolution With 100PX minus Of Its Height 
   https://jsfiddle.net/samudrala/frw31kbh/

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height:100vh;
}
header {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ff8800;
}
main {
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  height:-webkit- calc(100% - 100px);
  height:-moz-calc(100% - 100px);
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header></header>
  <main></main>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is also possible using flex box in css. But this will not support older browser like IE9 >.

```
<div class="flex">
  <header class="header"></header>
  <main class="flxGrow main"></main>
</div>

.flex{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column wrap;
  height:100%
}
.flxGrow{
  flex-grow:1;
}
.header{
  padding:20px;
  background:red;
}
.main{
  background:blue
}
body,html{
  height:100%;
  margin:0
}
```

Main advantage of using flexbox over vh(vertical height), No need of calculating manual heights of header. This solution will be flexible with any dynamic header heights. Also refer the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/uphvdng2/)